# why modelBuilder.Entity<T>().HasKey() works while HasKey() doesn't?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I wanted to config my EF Code First class using fluent API. I've tried this:

```
public class CenterMapping : ComplexTypeConfiguration<Center>
{
    public CenterMapping()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.ID);
    }
}
```

and VS tells me that `HasKey` doesn't exist. But when I try this:

```
public class YarigaranDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Center> Centers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CenterMapping());

        modelBuilder.Entity<Center>().HasKey(t => t.ID);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

it works fine. I'm using EF 6.1.1 and .Net 4.5. I've tried both VS 2015 preview and VS 2013 Community (just in case it's preview's problem)

Comment: I am assuming all of your usings are in place.  Like `using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration`

Comment: @DJBurb yep! since `ComplexTypeConfiguration<t>` is in `System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration` I have to implement it :)

Comment: Yeah I noticed that after I posted it

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: @DJBurb `The name 'HasKey' does not exist in the current context DataClasses`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to msdn: `ComplexTypeConfiguration` doesn't have a `HasKey` method.  Use `EntityTypeConfiguration`

```
public class CenterMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Center>
{
    public CenterMapping()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.ID);
    }
}
```